# reverse ordered traversal of a graph

Tags: c++, stl, graph-theory

This question is a result of strange behaviour that I am getting out of DFS graph traversal algorithm.i was trying to implement DFS and here is my code for it:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stack>
#include<vector>
#include<map>

using namespace std;
map<int,bool> discovered;

map< int , vector<int> > graph {
    {1,{2,3}},
    {2,{1,4,5}},
    {3,{1}},
    {4,{2}},
    {5,{2}}
};

vector <int> visited;
void clear_graph(){
for( map<int,bool>:: iterator iter = discovered.begin(); iter != discovered.end(); iter++)
    discovered[iter->first] = false;
}


void dfs( int start ) {    
    int current;
    int next;
    unsigned int i;
    stack <int> vertices;
    discovered[start] = true;
    vertices.push(start);

    while (!vertices.empty()){
        current = vertices.top();
        visited.push_back(current);
        vertices.pop();
        for( i = 0 ; i<graph[current].size() ; i++){
            next = graph[current][i];
            if ( !discovered[next] ){
                discovered[next] = true;
                vertices.push(next);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {    
    clear_graph();
    int start = 1;
    dfs(start);

    vector<int> ::iterator vi;
    for( vi=visited.begin(); vi!=visited.end();vi++)
        cout<<*vi<<" ";

    return 0;
}
```

This is the graph I am considering:

[image]

Output in the graph is : `1->2->4->5->3`
but output i am getting is : `1->3->2->5->4`

i can observe that its also a valid DFS traversal but in right to left oredr why is it so? if is wrong which part in my code i am going wrong? and this multiple traversals of a single graph wouldn't it produce incorrect results in cases where a DFS traversal is required?

Comment: In processing 1 you push 2 and 3 on the stack, in that order. Then you continue by popping 3, etc. BTW, your last sentence doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Barry sorry i am new to this i thought that would finally add the changes . my bad :). how do i add changes?

Comment: @ooga i edited it. that was a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a question of difference in algorithm.

If you do it recursively, you would iterate 2 completely before you backed up to 3, hence `1->2->4->5->3`. If you do it iteratively, you'd visit the neighbors in opposite order, so you'd end up iterating 3 completely first, hence `1->3->2->5->4`. Your algorithm is still a correct depth-first search algorithm, just different than the one the image happened to use.

If you want to keep your iterative solution but get the same result as the recursive one, you could just reverse your ordering. Change:

```
next = graph[current][i];
```

to:

```
next = graph[current][graph[current].size() - i - 1];
```

Comment: Thank you now it makes sense to me i should have tried the recursive algorithm too. But does the ordering of traversal matters?? just curious because two different implementation of a single algorithm produces two valid results.

Comment: @babysharma Nope. They're both valid - you're going depth-first, the breadth traversal order isn't important.

Answer (score 1):

Your traversal is reversed because you use stack data structure, which pops items in the reverse order (Last-In-First-Out) of how they were pushed into the stack. You push the vertices into the stack forwards, therefore you get them from the stack backwards.

Here are inline comments explaining why reversal of the traversal happens:

```
void dfs( int start ) {    
    int current;
    int next;
    unsigned int i;
    stack <int> vertices;
    discovered[start] = true;
    vertices.push(start);

    while (!vertices.empty()){
        // here you pop vertices from the stack in the reverse order of how
        // the vertices were pushed into the stack
        current = vertices.top();
        visited.push_back(current);
        vertices.pop();
        // here you traverse the vertices forward
        for( i = 0 ; i<graph[current].size() ; i++){
            next = graph[current][i];
            if ( !discovered[next] ){
                discovered[next] = true;
                // here you push vertices into the stack
                vertices.push(next);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i want to know the correctness of my algo .But does the ordering of traversal matters?? just curious because two different implementation of a single algorithm produces two valid results.

Comment: Serge, you just beat me by a minute :-)

Comment: @babysharma, your algorithm is generally correct. However, specific problems may require one or another particular traversal. Do you have any requirement about the order of traversal? Anyway, you now know how to alternate between forward and backward traversals.

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the child-nodes onto the stack in the order left to right. As a result, the right node will be popped and processed first. To traverse the children in left to right order change the for-loop to:

```
for (int i = graph[current].size()-1; i >= 0; --i)
```